# Loop API till null

Tags: c#, api, loops

I need some assistance with creating a loop until null is returned on a piece of software I've written.

The software basically takes information from an API call and deserializes it to a readable format for our online service. The difficulty I am facing is that when I make an API call it is only returning 100 records of employees when the client has far more than that.

```
foreach (var bankRecord in bankDetailDto.Value) //
{
     var deducRecords = deductions.Where(d => d.Ee_Number == bankRecord.EmployeeNumber).ToList();
     if (deducRecords.Any())
     {
         foreach(var deducRecord in deducRecords)
         {
             deducRecord.Bank_Account_Number = bankRecord.BankAccountNo;
             deducRecord.Bank_Account_Type = bankRecord.AccountType;
         }
     }
}
```

This is just an example of the loop I've tried to create but does not seem to work. I am under the impression i need to create a class to perhaps run a loop on the backround worker?

Apologize I have not been developing for very long.

Comment: Can you show the API call? Perhaps the standard call limits the number of records returned to 100 i.e., it pages the results and you are expected to call it again to get the next 100.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the API call has pagination with a limit is 100 per call, I think you need to use the while-loop and check if the API response still returns any object or not.

since you didn't include your API call code, I guess it's something like this

```cs
parameter.page = 1;
List<BankData> response = yourApi.yourApiAction(parameter);
while (response != null && response.Count > 0)
{
    ... do your logic to process the data here ...
    // Increase the pagination number
    parameter.page += 1;
    // Call the API again to get next page data
    response = yourApi.yourApiAction(parameter)
}
```

This is just an example code about how it should have been done.
Check your API documentation if it has pagination, and how to increase it.